# RoutedEventArgs error

Tags: silverlight

Basically a RoutedEvent travels through the Logical tree, either from top to bottom (Bubble event route) or bottom to top (Tunnel event route). 
What this means is that if you have a Button inside of a StackPanel, that itself is inside of a Grid; 
if you define a Click event in the controls they will all trigger it unless one of them handles it.
In my application I have:
Button -> StackPanel -> Grid
If it’s true, that StackPanel and Grid will not trigger it.

Grid -> StackPanel -> Button
if the Grid handles it, the StackPanel and Button will not trigger it.

in my application i wrote:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("http://www.legalbill.com");
}
```

it gave this-
Error - The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context            …
what it means n how will i move to desired site?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in wpf or silverlight..?

Comment: Response.Redirect is for ASP.NET... what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are trying to do this in wpf ? If you are trying in silverlight,It doesn't support `Response.Redirect`.You can use like this

using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Browser;
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
namespace Tips
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // execute one of them.
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(“http://www.silverlight.net“));
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(“http://www.silverlight.net“), “_blank”);
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(“http://www.silverlight.net“), “_blank”, “toolbar=0″);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 2 The name 'HtmlPage' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Make sure u import System.Windows.Browser.I have updated the answer